# Set the value in List<dynamic> not working

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have written a snippet for my large problem where I am setting a value in the same object after reading and formatting it. While the value is read from object location but it is not setting it.

I am accessing the object based on index and property.

```
class Student
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public double value1 { get; set; }
    public double value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Above is the POCO used to initialize the list. Below is the code where issue exisits

```
class ClassTest
{
    public static List<dynamic> GetUpdatedListCurrency(string[] CurrecyColumns, List<dynamic> dynamicList)
    {
        int Count = CurrecyColumns.Count();

        string first = CurrecyColumns.First();
        string two = CurrecyColumns.Skip(1).First();

        for (int i = 0; i < dynamicList.Count; i++)
        {
            var t = ((double)(dynamicList[i][first])).ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
            var tt = ((double)(dynamicList[i][two])).ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

            //Formatted value is availble at t and tt but it is not set back to that object

            dynamicList[i][first] = t;
            dynamicList[i][two] = tt;
        }

        return dynamicList;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student() { City="Noida", value1 = 44412, value2 = 33341 },
            new Student() { City="Delhi", value1 = 11212, value2 = 3421 }
        };

        var converter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic expandoObjectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list), converter);

        string Columns = " value1 as value3, value2 as value4";

        var res = ((List<ExpandoObject>)expandoObjectList)
                       .ToDynamicList().AsQueryable()
                       .Select("new (" + Columns + ")")
                       .ToDynamicList().ToList();

        string str = "value3,value4";
        var updatedList = GetUpdatedListCurrency(str.Split(','), res);

    }
}
```

Comment: While when I set the value directly with property name it works well. e.g. dynamicList[i].value4 =   ((double)(dynamicList[i][two])).ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So finally I sailed through it with other solution but I am still not clear why above should not set the value. Anyone indepth are welcome to answer in details. Below is the working code for me. I accessed the dynamic list with index and set the value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dynamicList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dynamicList[i].GetType().GetProperty(first)
                            .SetValue(dynamicList[i], ((double)(dynamicList[i][first])).ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr")), null);

                        dynamicList[i].GetType().GetProperty(two)
                            .SetValue(dynamicList[i], ((double)(dynamicList[i][first])).ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr")), null);
                    }
```